# postgres полнотекстовый индекс правильно ли я сделал?

Tags: postgresql

Значит так, нашел статью на сайте что бывает 3 типа индекса у postgres. Решил создать первый простой.

```
// добавляю специальное поле типа tsvector
ALTER TABLE "Doc" ADD "tsv" tsvector; 
// обновляем это поле лексемами
update "Doc" set "tsv" = to_tsvector("text");
// уже создаем индекс на основе этого поля
create index tsv on "Doc" using gin("tsv");
```

исходная база на диске занимает 1гб, вот на 2м этапе, где была генерация лексем, база вырастает в 2 раза, а на последнем этапе, где само создание индекса, еще на 400мб.

У меня вопрос, это норма? все верно я сделал? обязательно нужно промежуточное поле для генерации лексем? типа tsvector? или может можно без него?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> что бывает 3 типа индекса у postgres

6 вообще-то: btree, hash, gist, spgist, gin, brin. И это только из коробки оригинальной версии. В форках и расширениях могут быть и другие. Разработать новый `index access method` корректно задачка не самая простая - но возможная, и даже не требует изменения исходного кода самой СУБД, возможностей расширений достаточно для этого.

> update "Doc" set "tsv" = to_tsvector("text");

Postgresql - это MVCC СУБД, т.е. в таблице одновременно могут быть разные версии одной и той же строки, а update выглядит как delete+insert. Поэтому этим простеньким запросом вы именно удвоили размер таблицы и так и должно быть. Затем придёт процесс автовакуума, пометит удалённые строки как пустое место. Последующие insert'ы и update будут занимать место в начале таблицы, а пустые страницы в хвосте файла могут возвращаться обратно файловой системе. Ну или выполнить `vacuum full` для возврата места побыстрее (эксклюзивная блокировка таблицы, без блокировки - сторонние утилиты pgcompacttable, pg_repack)

400мб gin индекс на гигабайтный набор данных - выглядит вполне адекватно.

Промежуточное в общем случае поле не нужно, за ним следить можно попросить непосредственно индекс вот таким функциональным индексом:

```
create index tsv on "Doc" using gin(to_tsvector('english', "text"));
```

Запросы поиска соответственно выполнять `where to_tsvector('english', "text") ..` вместо `where tsv ...`

Указывать имя конфигурации полнотекстового поиска обязательно для построения индекса. Возможно вас интересует не `english`. Какой используется без указания конфига - определяет настройка `default_text_search_config`

Comment: Развернуто! спасибо!

Comment: ток чет стал выполнять vacuum full; и место снова побежало уменьшаться)

Comment: все норм уменьшилось где то на 200 мб

Comment: Да, не упомянул: vacuum full создаёт копию таблицы и всех индексов, затем подменяет ей исходную. Поэтому требует дополнительное место во время своей работы

Comment: слушай а может подскажешь как без отдельного поля сделать индекс, мне выдает ошибку functions in index expression must be marked immutable

Comment: мм, а, ну да. FTS в postgresql должен указываться с конфигом, `to_tsvector` с одним параметром использует `default_text_search_config` опцию и потому же не может быть `immutable`. `immutable` второй вариант `to_tsvector` с указанием конфига первым аргументом и индекс безопасно строить по нему только.

Comment: а какой конфиг указать? язык? щас попробую

Comment: ну да, чето стал делать, ошибка не выскочила